# What is the difference between ctypes.pointer, ctypes.POINTER, and ctypes.byref?

Tags: python, ctypes

In ctypes, what is the difference between pointer and byref? They both seem like a way to pass a pointer to a function, for example as an output parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionally, they are equivalent.

However, the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/ctypes-passing-pointers.html) do point out that

> pointer does a lot more work since it constructs a real pointer object, so it is faster to use byref if you don't need the pointer object in Python itself.

Comment: ... and POINTER (in upper case) constructs a pointer /type/, not a pointer object.

Comment: To me: this is not the answer, but the reason why the question got raised in my head. :-(