# Python Ctypes: Convert returned C array to python list, WITHOUT numpy

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using Python Ctypes to access some C library.

One of the functions I connected to, returns `const *double`, which is actually an array of doubles.

When I get the result in Python, how can I convert this array to a python list?

The signature of the C function:

```
const double *getWeights();
```

Let's assume that it returns an array that contains 0.13 and 0.12.
I want to get a python List: `[0.13, 0.12]`

Comment: Can you share what you have? What is the actual type of the object you've got in Python?

Comment: Let me clarify: if you're already using Python's ctypes to access this C library, what is the *Python* type of the returned object? i.e. if `result` is the return from your C function, what happens if you `print(type(result))` or `print(repr(result))` in Python?

Comment: c_double * `some_constant`

Comment: try simply `list(result)`

Comment: I tried but it returns some strange double values that I am sure that are not those that should be in the array

Comment: when I print as you asked, it shows `c_double_Array_2`

Comment: For which--`type` or `repr`? Is a memory address included in the result of `print(repr(result))`? If `repr` doesn't look like `'<c_double_Array_2 object at 0.0000000002B6EE48>'`, you're looking at a type instead of an actual instance.

Comment: If you have an actual `c_double_Array` instance, you should be able to just `list` it. If that's not working, please provide some test code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I finally solved it... Used `POINTER(c_double)` as returntype. Then used the pointer as an array, just like in C. Posted my answer for the public...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I succeeded solving it using pointers

The solution:

Define the function return type as `POINTER(double_c)`:

```
getWeights_function_handler.restype = POINTER(double_c)
```

When the function returns, you can use the `[]` operator to access the C array elements (the same operator used in C):

```
weights = getWeights_function_handler()
mylist = [weights[i] for i in xrange(ARRAY_SIZE_I_KNOW_IN_ADVANCE)]
```

Comment: how is it that I know the array size in advance?

Comment: You should find a way to know it in advance. Anyway, in C, if you don't "remember" an array size, you'll only be able to find it using some hack like `int array_length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(double);`, given that the array is `double[]`

Comment: You actually should be able to add an `int*` C function parameter, where the array length will be written by the C function, so that you can know it in Python when the function returns. Passing such a parameter from Python to C should be possible using `ctypes.byref()` or `ctypes.pointer()`. Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530473/ctypes-and-passing-a-by-reference-to-a-function

Comment: For difference between `ctypes.byref()` and `ctypes.pointer()`, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281306/what-is-the-difference-between-ctypes-pointer-ctypes-pointer-and-ctypes-byref